# what can I use for a messenger server in Java

Tags: java, java-server

instead of java socket, what else I can use for a messenger server in Java.

My goal is to maintain more client.I know a little about RMI. But I'm not sure what should I use. I want to maintain more than 100,000 client at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information I would suggest JMS.

100,000 client is a lot. Is this concurrent clients or registered clients?

Is this on the internet, or internal network?

Comment: How many concurrent clients will you need to support? For an internet application I would suggest having a gateway application which sits in front of the JMS server.  JMS is not simple to secure.

Comment: ActiveMQ and HornetQ are good suggestions and you can change one for the other relatively easily. You can code it so its just a configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need JMS with clustered broker (I'd recommend HornetQ).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache ActivemQ, its easy to get started with. Find more about ActivemQ [here](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're asking so I'm sorry if this is a terrible answer but I'll do my best. If you have a deadline to meet I would use a well coded library like JMS, however I haven't ever looked at the source code but I'd say its a safe bet it uses Sockets. If there is another way to make the type of connection you're trying to I don't know what it is.

If this is for personal use or educational purposes I would make your own, that's how I learned. I studied some source code I found and java2s.com for a chat program then made my own implementation. The program I made is more like an instant messenger than a chat, I did it in Java because it's easy to programs cross-platform and I think that's important for something like an instant messenger.

If you'd like to take a look at the source code send me your e-mail address. My e-mail address is kevin.bigler3@gmail.com. Good luck, sorry I couldn't be more help.